# Error 1062 when trying to REMOVE a part of a primary key

Tags: mysql

I am trying to untick the box "PN", hence, remove a column as a primary key to avoid having a multiple primary key in a table.

However, when trying to apply changes, it says

> Error 1062: Duplicate entry '29' for key 'PRIMARY'...

Most of the existing questions for this error are for adding a column.

Comment: That's why you had a composite PK in the first place, because the first column doesn't have unique values. You have to remove the PK entirely and create a new one. You should post the schema of your table if you want real answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per @emix comment, the PK that will remain once I remove the other PK is not a unique key (UQ), i.e, has unique values. What I did to solve this issue is, I made sure that the PK that I will retain is NN and UQ.